# cakephp 3 using scopes when logging

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I configured a logger for my orders in `app.php`

```
'orders' => [
    'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'file' => 'orders',
    'levels' => ['info'],
    'scopes' => ['orders'],
]
```

and then in one model of mine I did:

```
 Log::info("There's an order", 'orders');
```

I expected the log message being written only in `orders.log` but it shows in `debug.log` too.

according to documentation:

> If there is a configured logger for that scope, the log messages will
>   be directed to those loggers. If a log message is written to an
>   unknown scope, loggers that handle that level of message will log the
>   message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably worth simply debugging  [where the log method looks for a stream](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Log/Log.php#L376).

Comment: so the default behavior is that a logger with no scopes will catch all the message (if they match its levels), right? I come from cake 2 and it worked different, but I see now that is because cake 2 let you use custom levels (types) so you can do `write('orders', 'message', 'orders')` while in cake 3 this generates an exception. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

As I wandering around, I found this: https://github.com/DaoAndCo/cakephp-logging

To restrict scope to one logger, add this to default logger config:

```
'scopes' => false
```

Like this:

```
'debug' => [
    'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'file' => 'debug',
    'levels' => ['notice', 'info', 'debug'],
    'scopes' => false,
    'url' => env('LOG_DEBUG_URL', null),
],
'error' => [
    'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'file' => 'error',
    'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    'scopes' => false,
    'url' => env('LOG_ERROR_URL', null),
],
```

That's it! Work like a charm! I also did test it.

Answer (score 0):

'queries' => [ 'className' => FileLog::class, 'path' => LOGS, 'file' => 'queries', 'url' => env('LOG_QUERIES_URL', null), 'scopes' => ['queriesLog'], ],

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?